# How to get the working directory path?

Tags: snakemake

I'm wondering how to manage paths in my Snakefiles. Say I have this configuration:

```
current_dir
current_dir/snakefiles
current_dir/configfiles
```

and I execute my workflows this way:

```
current_dir$ snakemake -s snakefiles/my_snakefile --configfile configfiles/my_config.yml
```

I know I can get the path to my Snakefile using the global variable `workflow.snakefile`, but I would like to get also:

- the path to my configfile
- the path where I'm executing my snakefile, e.g. `current_dir`

How to achieve this? Are there other global variables in Snakemake, that I'm not aware of?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

The working directory is set via Python. You can get it with `os.getcwd()`. Also please note that there is a canonical way to organize Snakemake workflows: http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/project_info/faq.html#what-is-the-recommended-way-to-distribute-a-snakemake-workflow.

While you can of course use something else, following this scheme helps others to understand your workflow. There might of course be cases where this does not fit.

Comment: Thanks, indeed my organization is a bit different. I'm separating config files, workflows and rules. A given workflow can run with different config files, and one config file can be used by different workflows. That's why I would like to be able to get the config file path anywhere (in workflows and in rules).